# SMTP server sending rate guidelines

Tags: email, smtp

I am build a tool that initiates an SMTP transaction with a domain to see if (a) that domain can receive emails and (b) the desired address exists on that domain. I will be batching large groups of email addresses (10,000+ at a time), but I don't want to bombard the server and get blacklisted. Are there guidelines for how often is it safe to communicate with an SMTP server?

I know about the `VRFY` command, but it is not implemented across the board. I plan to attempt to use the VRFY command and fall back to using,

```
MAIL From:<user@example.com>
RCPT To:<first.last@example.org>
QUIT
```

to see if the message will be deliverable. Again, are there guidelines on how often I can initiate an SMTP transaction like this on a domain?

**Edit:**
The purpose of this is to create a tool that my organization can use to (a) clean some bad emails from several largely inactive lists so that we do not have to pay our email delivery system to send potentially thousands of emails that will bounce, and (b) check an email when a user subscribes to a list so that we reject emails like aoghuifdgsiuvb@gmail.com.

Comment: In order to prevent dictionary attacks like this, many sites will silently accept the `RCPT TO:` for any user in their domain, and only return a bounce message later in the transaction, or silently drop the message if it is spammy.  Thus the results you can achieve with this method are tentative at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, spamming is bad. Always ask user wheter she wants to receive newsletters.

1. "Unsort" mail addresses by domain, leaving the "distance" between e-mail addresses with same domain as big possible.
2. I think it's not the programmer's decision. There should be a config value which tells a minimum amount of time between two mail sending to the same domain. You should set up a limit also for that config value, avoid setting it to zero or low value.

Answer (score 1):

The only universal guideline I believe can be offered is "don't do this". If you behave like a spammer, you will be treated like a spammer.  In the optimistic scenario, sites will already have controls in place, and silently throttle or block you. In less ideal scenarios, they will initiate actions against you on the (reasonable) assumption that you are collecting addresses for a spam list.

Answer (score 0):

A better soluton would be to actually follow through the whole SMTP session, sending a user an email with a verification code/link. This has the advantage of showing that the user actually has control of the address in question and it keeps you from looking like a spam bot.

Volume is not as much the issue as reputation. Let the user know you're about to send them an email in your web flow. This means they're much less likely to mark it as spam.

Answer (score 0):

some hosts have clear and defined guidelines as to how many emails can be sent per hour.
So i guess this would depned onyour hostng service provider, UNLESS your hosting your own mail server off course.